# Send email to email submitted in a php form

Tags: mysql, email, php

I would appreciate if someone could point in the right direction when it comes to mail sending with php. I have this contest form http://www.beogradstore.com/mn/contest/main-contest/ and I would like my contest entrants to receive email notifications when they enter the contest AND whenever they receive new entries via referral links. Entries are stored in an SQL table.

What would be the best way to achieve this? Is it using php mail function or something else? Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What OS does your PHP server have?

Comment: http://php.net/mail? Of course, that function's garbage for "real" work, and you should be using Swiftmailer or PHPMailer instead.

Comment: My PHP server has Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the PHP `mail()` function.  Here's an example below of an HTML email:

```
    $subject = "Subject";
    $msg = '
    <html>
    <body>
    <p>HTML email here</p>
    </body>
    </html>
    ';
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: Their Name <info@theirdomain.com>' . "\r\n";
    $email = 'info@yourdomain.com';
    if(!mail($email, $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
        // Show error
    }
```

Comment: I have something like that. However, I need to setup email notifications whenever my entrants are rewarded with new entries. Have any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: How are they rewarded with new entries? This can be added in a page that manages that or you can have it within a script called by a cron job.

Comment: They are rewarded with new entries whenever new entrants enter the contest via referral link. So, let's say you enter the contest, you will receive a referral link which you can share via facebook, twitter, google, etc. Whenever new entrants enter the contest with that link, you will be rewarded with 10 new entries.

Comment: Use your MySQL database to save the entries, and every time one is added (with the same referral link or however you want to match them), use `mysql_num_rows()` (on the same page the referrals are being entered in the database) to see if it is equal to 9, if it is, send the email.

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in `mail()` function to send emails from your PHP app.

For more advanced use cases, including attachements, HTML emails, sending via Gmail, etc. you can use a library like PHPMailer:

http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/